# Using Jquery keyPress() to capture key stokes on keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have a keyboard I am trying to highlight yellow when a key is pressed. Currently I have it working to highlight each key yellow upon being pressed but I can't figure out how to use a keyboard event to capture the key being released to remove the yellow background upon release.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
$('#'+ event.which).css("background-color","yellow"); 
});
```

I currently have the id's of all the keys labeled as their ASCII codes as well.

Comment: What do you expect `(document)` to evaluate to?

Comment: sorry i meant $(document)

Comment: Sounds like you just want two event handlers; `keydown` and `keyup`

Comment: I've tried  keydown but the background color doesnt change. not getting any errors in console either

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on how keyboard events are dispatched. [MDN has a good article on it. Pay attention to the Notes section.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)